# Map of maps in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD which looks like this:

```
print rdd.collect():
[
    ('id2', u'lion'),
    ('id5', u'dolphin'),
    ('id2', u'tiger'),
    ('id2', u'lion'),
    ('id3', u'dolphin'),
    ('id3', u'monkey'),
]
```

Is it possible to create a map of maps in pyspark which would count the occurances of each animal by id? 
For example:

```
id2: {lion: 2, tiger: 1}, id3: {dolphin:1, monkey: 1}, id5: {dolphin: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurence of each animal. But you need a counter for each item ID.

You can create a dictionary of counters like this:

```py
import collections

items = [
    ('id2', u'lion'),
    ('id5', u'dolphin'),
    ('id2', u'tiger'),
    ('id2', u'lion'),
    ('id3', u'dolphin'),
    ('id3', u'monkey'),
]

counters = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
for item_id, animal in items:
    counters[item_id][animal] += 1
print(counters)
```

Output:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
            {'id2': Counter({'lion': 2, 'tiger': 1}),
             'id3': Counter({'dolphin': 1, 'monkey': 1}),
             'id5': Counter({'dolphin': 1})})
```

The result is a dictionary of counters.